Unable to install Ubuntu 24.10 from USB (not loading live file)
I have Asus UX410UFR laptop with 20GB RAM and i5-8250U. I tried to install Ubuntu 24.10 to move from Windows 11, but I can't load even a live CD to start the installation process.
What I tried to do:

Downloaded ISO of Ubuntu 24.10 from ubuntu.com
Created a USB stick (I tried both Rufus and balenaEtcher)
Tried different USB ports to insert a USB stick
Turned off Security Boot in BIOS and other UEFI settings which probably could interrupt installation or mounting file system.

Every time I get 2 similar errors after selecting "Try Ubuntu or install":

Unable to find a medium containing a live file system (after burning USB with Rufus)
GPT PMBR size mismatch will be corrected by write.

It would be great if someone could explain how to fix this problem.


The error "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system" is usually the result of an invalid ISO (did you validate it to ensure its perfect?) OR bad write of ISO to install media (which can be triggered by reformat of ISO using options; QA involves no changes where as programs like rufus can change the ISO thru reformat where you must use specific options matching your hardware).  I suggest validating ISO & simple clone (no change) write of ISO to media.

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. The minimal USB downloads the packages for you eliminating the possibility of downloading an  invalid ISO.

I checked this link and tried again. It didn’t worked for me.
